# how to use YouTube Api in Angular 6 project in component not root

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube-api, components

So here is a catch, how to use Youtube Api in angular project, in precise component?

I have called youtube api script in html and also made an regular api embed script to make a call with 
`<div id="player"></div>` and video/iframe comes up, but only in root path, not in other components where i want. Video in other components is not fired by script, div remains untouched.

How to achieve this, to work for other components?

On top of that, i am using div with click function to toggle between pause and play, so basically i want to manipulate with video without use to touch YouTube controls. Angular project navigation is controlled by keyboard, so youtube controls and projects are colliding.

How to achieve this also ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I recommend you use this npm library... 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-youtube-player
very easy to use in your angular app
support angular 5+

Also 
 example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-youtube-player?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thank you for comment, i did use but never got the library work for me.
I updated my question up, didn't mention that i want on top of video to use div that onclick toggles play and pause of video.
In ngx-youtube-player i never got it working and also never got related videos on the end to disable, so does controls and modestbranding etc..

Comment: what do you mean? 
Do you want  bind click on div to stop video?

Comment: I have achieved to make this happen with ngx-youtube-player by adding this in component.ts, binding click on div to stop and play video

  `toggleVideo() {
    this.player.playVideo()
    if (this.ytEvent == 1) {
      this.player.pauseVideo()
    } else {
      this.ytEvent == 2
      this.player.playVideo()
    }
  }`

What i am having issues now is parameters for youtube video, like related videos and controls, and also modestbranding, how to disable all of this in ngx-youtube-player

Comment: if i understand  
you want disabled native controls methods in youtube api?

Comment: right now i want to disable related videos on the end of video, and also controls of youtube. In iframe i would just add on the end of link ?rel=1?controls=0 etc etc and in youtube api i would just use playerVars

but in ngx-youtube-player i do not know how to achieve same.

Comment: you can play with native method of this ngx-youtube play; 
for example: 

onStateChange(event) {
    // here you can handle every event player
    this.ytEvent = event.data;
  }
  savePlayer(player) {
    this.player = player;
  }
  
  playVideo() {
   // here i changed  this.player.playVideo(); to this.player.pauseVideo();
   // now when user clicked on play video we stop video and so on...
    this.player.pauseVideo();
  }
  
  pauseVideo() {
    this.player.pauseVideo();
  }
}
just read about all features of this library i think it can help  you